# Android Bitmap shaped Rhomboid

Tags: android, bitmap, skew

I have to implement Bitmap whose shape is like a rhomboid(For ref. I have attached sample image for it.) and the source image is rectangular. I do want to make the image to be skewed, cut the image in this shape.

[image: Sample view of Gallery]

Can anyone give me any idea how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Path of the shape you need and use the canvas.clipPath() method prior to drawing each of the bitmaps.

I have done this with a circle:

```
Path mPath = new Path();

mPath.addCircle(centerx, centery, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.REPLACE);
canvas.drawBitmap(....);
```

There are various path methods that you can use to create the desired path (path.addArc, path.lineTo, etc).